# python socket beginner error

Tags: python, sockets

I just started coding in python I can't the encryption part of strings 
I am trying to run this simple server client code 
(The client is to run on raspberry-pi) 
server :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import socket

server_socket = socket.socket()
server_socket.bind(('0.0.0.0', 8000))
server_socket.listen(0)
BUFFER_SIZE = 24
conn, addr = server_socket.accept()
print ('Got connection from', addr)
while 1:
    data = conn.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
    if not data: break
    print ("received data:", data)
    conn.send(data)  # echo
    conn.close()
```

Client:(were I have the error)

```
import socket
client_socket = socket.socket()
client_socket.connect(("192.168.1.4", 8000))
BUFFER_SIZE = 1024
MESSAGE = "Hello, World!"
client_socket.send(MESSAGE)
data = client_socket.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
client_socket.close()

print ("received data:", data)
```

The error here =:

```
 File"c.py" line 9, in <module>
 client_socket.send<MESSAGE>
 typeError:'str' does not support the buffer interface
```

Comment: you're using python3, and you can only send bytes, not strings. `client_socket.send(MESSAGE.encode('utf8'))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In python3 the interface to `socket.send()` changed to accept bytes instead of a string. See the difference between [Python 3 docuentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.send) and [Python 2 documenation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.socket.send).

The solution is to encode the string before passing it to `send()` as follows:

```
client_socket.send(MESSAGE.encode())
```

Comment: Thanks it worked but no connection between the server and the client

Answer (score 0):

In Python 3x strings are unicode, and they have to be encoded to bytes to send to a socket. The line:

```
client_socket.send(MESSAGE)
```

needs to be changed to:

```
client_socket.send(MESSAGE.encode('utf-8'))
```

On the server side you can decode data to get a string.